# Reflection from Texture Coordinate Node is stretched

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, texture-coordinates

I'm having a problem, or I've found a bug. I'm trying to change the reflection of an extruded cylinder (basically a drinking glass), and the output from the Texture Coordinates node is stretched. Nothing I do seems to affect it. Reseting UV map - changing to other UV mapping. Nothing.

Scale is properly applied.

Adding a default cylinder works fine. However, when I add geometry (either extruding or adding edge loops) to the cylinder, it messes up like the extruded glass.

The only way I can get it to behave is if I scale the faces out a little from the glass. BUT These faces are still perfectly aligned with each other like they were before being scaled out as a group.

Images below:
1. Standard Cylinder on the left, glass on the right

[image: Standard Cylinder on the left, glass on the right]

2. Standard Cylinder on the left, glass with middle faces scaled out some on the right

[image: Standard Cylinder on the left, glass with middle faces scaled out some on the right]

3. Node set up.

[image: Node set up]